# Count the number of the personages in a book

Tags: data, text

A novel [Vanity Fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanity_Fair_(novel)) by William Thackeray has many different characters in it, such as Emmy Sedley, Becky Sharp, and Rawdon Crowley. Is it possible to use *Mathematica* to automatically count the number of the characters in the novel?

As another example, one could consider how to exactly  count the approximately 600 characters in [And Quiet Flows the Don](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Quiet_Flows_the_Don) by Mikhail Sholokhov.

Here is [a link to the plain text](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/599).

```
Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/599/pg599.txt"]
```

Comment: If the text is stored in variable `str`, the number of characters can be given by `StringLength[str]`. How to import the text is another question and I don't think questions such as "find a free version of this book for me" is in the scope of mma.se. **edit** I think I misunderstood character = person and character = element of a string.

Comment: @anderstood: Thank you for your interest. Of course, character = personage.

Comment: @ C. E.: Thank you for your interest. Frankly saying, I only looked in Text Analysis.

Comment: It was very easy to mistake "number of characters" for "string length" in the original question, so I rephrased it a bit. Why did you pick that text if you don't have access to a digital version of it that you can share? Please update the question with a link to a text. Also I think you should have made some headway on this yourself, at the very least you should have imported the text into *Mathematica*. Please share that code.

Comment: @ C. E. Thank you. I somewhat improved your English.

Comment: @user64494 No you didn't. My English was fine, you introduced grammatical errors into the text and made it harder to read. But your intention was good, and it's your question so it's all good. And thank you for adding the link to Gutenberg.

Comment: This will be hard in general. This may be a start for you: `t1 = StringSplit[
   Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/599/pg599.txt"]];
p1 = Tally[
   Select[Partition[t1, 2, 1], 
    And @@ (StringLength[#1] > 2 && 
          UpperCaseQ[StringTake[#1, 1]] &) /@ #1 &]];
p2 = Select[p1, 
   DictionaryWordQ[#1[[1, 1]]] && DictionaryWordQ[#1[[1, 2]]] &];
p3 = Select[p2, 
   LowerCaseQ[
     StringTake[#1[[1, 1]], {2, 2}] <> 
      StringTake[#1[[1, 2]], {2, 2}]] &];
p4 = (Reverse[SortBy[#1, Last]] &)[
   Select[p4, StringMatchQ[StringJoin[#1[[1]]], __?LetterQ] &]];
Column@p4`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Mathematica problem. It is an unsolved AI problem.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Could you elaborate your statement about an unsolved AI problem? I don't find it here https://medium.com/ai-roadmap-institute/unsolved-problems-in-ai-38f4ce18921d#.9ag86frwf .

Comment: @Rolf Mertig: Many thanks from me to you for your constructive comment.

Comment: @m_goldberg It is unsolvable by Mathematica alone. If one adds database-queries of list of (first) names, then one could probably get pretty far with a semi-heuristic approach as I laid out above. But I agree that this question should be closed as "too-difficult" or whatever the reason is to close a research-type question.