# Extract names from a document

Tags: ocr, computer-vision

If I have a document, any document, it can be a book, an article, etc, how could I extract people's names from there?

For example, if the input is an article, the output of the function would be the authors.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question - please consider adding more detail and a _specific_ example. In the meantime, my first thought would be to split the text into words (using TextWords) and checking against some very long dataset of names that I'm sure is available on the internet somewhere.

Comment: ...and a difficult question that needs semantic document analysis for its solution.  After all, suppose the name "Mark Stone" is listed.  You'll never extract that name based on simple semantics as both names are standard words.  You'll need to know where authors are listed on a document, that a sentence refers to a *person*, and so on.  Much harder than the poser would imagine, I bet.

Comment: What if you trained a neural network to pull names out of text?

Comment: You would likely need hundreds of millions of training documents in which the target names were pre-identified.  A tricky task worthy of a Masters Degree thesis or a small startup company, such as the companies that parse resumes and other documents.

Comment: *hundreds of millions* might be a slight exaggeration.

Comment: Duplication of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139305/count-the-number-of-the-personages-in-a-book .

Comment: @user64494 a duplicate of a question that has been closed as off-topic... I agree with Carl, the main problem here is that this is too broad, and therefore [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD). Liuba, Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because its unanswerable for lack of details. We can't help unless you [edit] your question to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) and make it specific, with all the details one would need to reproduce your problem exactly. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Answer (score 4):

You may use the functions in the [Text Analysis](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TextAnalysis.html) guide to extract the `"NounPhrase"`s containing `"ProperNoun"`s.  This gives a short list of proper nouns to evaluate for people names.

First collect some text that contains people's names in the form of a Wikipedia article using [`WikipediaData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WikipediaData.html).

```
articleText = WikipediaData["Garrett Morgan"];
```

The article's text can be separated into sentences using [`TextSentences`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextSentences.html).

```
txtSentences = TextSentences[articleText];
```

Version 10.3 added the experimental function [`TextStructure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextStructure.html) that breaks a text down into its grammatical structure using [`TextElement`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextElement.html)s.

```
txtStruc = TextStructure[First@txtSentences, "ConstituentTree"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Using the nested structure of the `"ConstituentTree"` (evaluate `FullForm@txtStruc`) the `"NounPhrase"`s containing `"ProperNoun"`s can be extracted by using [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html).

```
properNounPrases =
 StringRiffle /@
  Cases[TextElement[w_String, _Association] :> w] /@
   First /@
    Cases[
     TextStructure[txtSentences, "ConstituentTree"]
     ,
     TextElement[
      {TextElement[_String, 
        <|
          "GrammaticalUnit" -> Entity["GrammaticalUnit", "ProperNoun" | "Punctuation"]
        |>] ..},
      <|"GrammaticalUnit" -> Entity["GrammaticalUnit", "NounPhrase"]|>
      ],
     Infinity
     ];
```

This produces a short list of proper nouns to consider.

```
Multicolumn[DeleteDuplicates@properNounPrases, 
 Frame -> All, 
 FrameStyle -> LightGray, 
 ItemSize -> Full]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

From `properNounPrases` you could then continue either select by hand or compare to some database or train some net to select the names for you.

Hope this helps.