# Extracting Parts of Speech

Tags: associations, natural-language

I am looking to parse the ConstituentsTree from TextStructure.
Someone already asked how to get the proper nouns out of a text here:
[Extract names from a document](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180754/extract-names-from-a-document/180758#180758)

I am looking for a more general approach to extracting the constituents from a constituents tree. [image: Constituent Tree]

In this case how could you extract the proper noun from the noun phrase and the noun from the noun phrase in the verb phrase?
In the referenced post it is done by getting the associations form the FullForm of the tree but I can't figure out how to replicate it so it can be used for more general purposes. Thanks

Comment: My own feeble attempts at this sort of problem start from the `"ConstituentStrings"` of the `TextStructure` and then do some string processing.